# Change locale for Chart.js in React

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, momentjs

I'm trying to set the locale of [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org) in a React application.

#### Method 1

[Use the bundled](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html) `Chart.js` version, since I do not use `moment` in the rest of the app:

`import Chart from 'chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js';`

**Problem:** How can I set the locale? `moment` is not available as a global object, nor can I find it as a property of `Chart` or any of its instances, nor is there an API to modify the locale.

#### Method 2

[Use the non bundled](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html) version and include `moment` myself.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/es';
import Chart from 'chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js';
```

Then in code before rendering the chart:

```
moment.locale('es');
chart = new Chart(type, options);
```

**Problem:** but this does throws an error:

`Error: Chart.js - Moment.js could not be found! You must include it before Chart.js to use the time scale. Download at https://momentjs.com`

I have tried assigning `moment` to the local object as `window.moment = moment` but same error.

#### (Method) Hack 3

Just to test I copied `moment.js` and `es.js` files to `public` folder and included them as `<script>` tags in `index.html` and it worked, but I don't want a hack like that.

**Notes**

I know of some React libraries for Chart.js but do not want to use them.

I have read other post where they suggest reloading the chart if the locale was changed before it was rendered.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202587/chart-js-moment-locale][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202587/chart-js-moment-locale]

https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/101

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5284

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2906

Answer (score 0):

in Vue I tried whit.

```
import Moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/es';
import Chart from 'chart.js';
Moment.locale('es');
```

it worked for me.

I was looking in the chart.js code ant I see, they call moment as `Moment` not `moment`